# Get certain element on a page to manipulate its value (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a specific question about a forum page I visit often, which I'm trying to manipulate locally with a custom script (extension).

[This one for example](http://www.antronio.cl/threads/para-variar-declaran-alerta-roja-por-incendio-forestal-en-sector-laguna-verde-en-valpara%C3%ADso.1251437/)

Looking at the code I can see that every message has its own section, and inside them there's a DIV with the id "likes-post-xxxx" where you can see on the page the users that gave the post a "thanks" or a "like". That DIV is always present, even when the post have no "thanks", but when it does there's an optional part that shows what users gave the thanks and an element with the Class "OverlayTrigger" that groups users on a pop-up when they are more than 4 I think.

My question is how can I get to this "OverlayTrigger" element, when it exists within a message, to get its contents (the number) and then manipulate the entire message that actually have this element to mark it in some way (like, change its color when there are certain number of users in the element, etc).

I've tried getting the element by Class Name but ended up with undefined values, I guess is because the number of messages on a page doesn't correspond to the actual number of elements containing the "thanks" since not all the posts have them.

All this in HTML/Javascript.

Comment: What efforts did you make?

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: There maybe ajax rendering the content, so when you try to access the classname it doesn't exist yet. View source of the html to ensure the classnames exists on page load. If not, then you will need to create a javascript timer to wait for it to load, or provide a document.ready or window.onload method before accessing the content.

Comment: I don't have an actual code at hand but I tried a couple of ways (I'm kinda learning on the go); for example grabbing the elements like this "var likes = document.getElementsByClassName("OverlayTrigger");" and then just run an iteration to get the values (innerHTML). I assume the values of the class element are stored on an array so I check for every of them, but that's when I get the "undefined" error. Something like this:  for (var i = 0; i <= likes.length; i++){
var aux = likes[i].innerHTML;}